# Can the stack size be changed dynamically - How?

Tags: c, stack

Can the stack size be changed dynamically in C?

If yes, How?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Calling a function or entering a block with local variable extend the stack, but it doesn't seem likely that this is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: a little side note: use `alloca()` to get space on the current stacj in the current function. (@AProgrammer)

Answer (score 6):

It depends on OS you are using.

On Unix/Linux you can use POSIX syscall `setrlimit()` for `RLIMIT_STACK` resource.

See `man setrlimit` for details.

Answer (score 2):

By dynamically do you mean changing the stack size while the code is in execution? AFAIK, that cannot be done. But, you can set the stack size before you run your application. You can do this by using the "ulimit -s" command in linux which will set the stack size for all process executed under that shell.

Incase of windows, the same can be done in VC6 for that project by setting the stack size in Project Properties->link options->output->stack allocations->reserve. I am not aware for VC8, but such options might be available.

Answer (score 2):

In a single-threaded program under Linux, the stack will grow automatically until it crashes into something else in the memory space. This is usually the heap and on 32-bit systems this means that you can typically have several GB of stack.

In a multi-threaded program, this isn't generally possible as another thread's stack will be in the way.

You can control the stack size when creating a new thread, but this is generally a bad idea as it is architecture-dependent how much stack is required by a task.

It's pretty low level stuff and mostly controlled by your C library / threading library. Mess around at your peril :)

Comment: Technically, with virtual memory it should be possible to move things around to make a space for growing stack. So, even multi-threaded programs could have dynamic stacks if that was supported.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's something that can't be done robustly because address space needs to be reserved for the stack. If objects were already allocated on the heap with addresses within the new desired stack-range, you'd be in big trouble. On systems with less memory than address space it could be possible, but I doubt you'll see many systems that allow it. C does not require nor support any such mechanisms for it.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is outside the scope of C.

Answer (score -3):

Why do you need to do this? It depends on the OS and isn't something that C itself gets directly involved in (although specific linkers and runtime environments have varying ways of managing the configuration of such things).

What OS have you got, and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: this is the kind of answer I hate: "why would anyone do that". 
If you don't have an answer, keep silent. He probably has reason to ask. I actually had the same problem. The answer is of course: google rlimit. And I still have no answer for windows...
Now, to answer your question: what if he has to implement an interactive development environment, or a language interpreter, where a user can enter an arbitrary script to be executed. If the script needs lots stack (a recursive one), the runtime system ought to support that (catch the stack-overflow, change the limit and proceed) - right ?

Comment: @blabla999: I'm always happy to have a downvote with an explanation, esp a good deep one. On reflection, this 'probing question' should have been a comment. Having said that, in terms of information content, it's ~= @kotlinski's answer which you Meh'd. The bottom line is that I was trying to help the process - sometimes I do that by voting and adding "cmon, more detail" in the question comments, sometimes I do it by giving half the answer and moving on. But I do appreciate that you have sound foundations for your stance and will take this on board as a bigger push to defaulting to comments